# Binary image blob movement prediction with optical flow

Tags: glsl, motion

I got stuck with a problem: I have two binary images A and B, which differ by a few seconds. There are Blobs in the images which move (imagine a binary image of a lava lamp). Now I calculate the optical flow of those two images (using Lucas Kanade) which results in an "image" containing the motion vectors. As the image is binary, I obviously only get the movement of the outline of the blob.
Now the question: using the GPU (GLSL preferred), how to calculate a prediction of an image C following image B for every pixel? I can use the motion vector of the outline to see where it moved to. But how would I do this for the "inside" pixels where I don't have optical flow information?

I thought about searching for the edge in the fragment shader but this could possibly involve an excessive amount of texture lookups? Or downsample the image and do the search in the downsampled version to reduce texture lookups?

For clarification: There are many blobs in the image. The blobs are not (necessarily) konvex.